# Automatic Reload on Install

Tags: safari, safari-extension

When a script is injected in a safari extension it runs on page load, so that means when an extension is installed the injected javascript will only apply to newly-opened pages or pages which are reloaded afterwards. Does anyone know how to ensure the javascript is run without having to reload?

Alternatively, forcing users to load... this seems a bit dangerous though.

Comment: I'm not sure that the question is clear. It certainly isn't to me. Scripts can be injected on start or end of the page load. They are loaded on each request and for each embedded HTML-sourced element (e.g. iframes).

Comment: Why do you need to automagically reload the page once an extension is installed?

Comment: Well I guess I don't necessarily want it to automatically reload, but because the scripts are injected before or after page load, the extension does not take immediate effect, which is what I'd like to achieve. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: well, yeah, but I don't see why it's *so* important it takes effect _now_. What does your extension do?

Comment: It inserts an iframe into the page displaying some links to an online child safety website. Essentially, I'd just like it to take immediate effect so that it doesn't appear to be broken. The average user doesn't know that it's normal to need to reload, I think.

It's not hugely important, it's just a little niggle.

Comment: I'd also find this useful -- I'm writing an extension now that detects certain content on a page and acts accordingly, and even just for testing purposes it's a pain having to reload pages every time I rebuild/reinstall the extension. Obviously users don't have to deal with that, but I agree it can make the extension appear 'broken' until the user loads a new page, or reloads the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

I've also tried to find a way to "execute" or "attach" a script on install. This is possible in Chrome and Firefox, without having to reload the page. Unfortunately in Safari I haven't found a way to do this without having to reload the page and let the normal addContentScript handlers take care of injecting the script.

To reload all Safari tabs directly after extension has been installed:

```
/* In glabal.js */

// Reloads all tabs
function reloadTabs() {
  var browserWindows = safari.application.browserWindows;
  for (var i = 0; i < browserWindows.length; i++) {
    var tabs = browserWindows[i].tabs;
    for (var j = 0; j < tabs.length; j++) {
      tabs[j].url = tabs[j].url;
    }
  }
}

// Called on first run
function onInstall() {
  reloadTabs();
}

var firstRun = localStorage['extensionHasPreviouslyRun'] === undefined ||
    !JSON.parse(localStorage['extensionHasPreviouslyRun']);

if (firstRun) {
  onInstall();
  localStorage['extensionHasPreviouslyRun'] = JSON.stringify(true);
}
```

Comment: Oops. I missed that localStorage only handles strings, so we have to compensate for that, for instance by introducing JSON.parse and JSON.stringify. Answer has been updated.